# Como retornar array validado para um formulário?

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema de inscrição `step-by-step` que seria passo a passo, ou seja primeiro o usuário informa alguns dados depois outros e outros... Quero ir validando esses dados com `PHP` (pois tenho que fazer consulta no banco de dados para ver se o usuário já existe). Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<form  method="post" action="forms/register.php">
    <div class="modal-content modal-person modal-person2">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title md-title">Registrar</h4>
            <h5 class="modal-title md-title">login</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <?php
            if (isset($_REQUEST['error'])) {
                $erro = $_REQUEST['error'];
                if ($erro == "userexist") {
                    echo "<b class=\"text-danger\">Usuário ou email já cadastrado!</b>";
                    echo "<p class=\"text-danger\">Veja-os novamente..<br><br>";
                } else if ($erro == "passdistint") {
                    echo "<b class=\"text-danger\">Senhas são distintas!</b>";
                    echo "<p class=\"text-danger\">Os campos de senha devem ter a mesma senha..<br><br>";
                } else if ($erro == "every") {
                    echo "<b class=\"text-danger\">Erro desconhecido!</b>";
                    echo "<p class=\"text-danger\">Tente novamente mais tarde...<br><br>";
                } else if ($erro == "sucess") {
                    echo "<script>
                    $(function(){
                        if($('.ativo').next().size())
                        {
                            $('.ativo')
                                .hide(800)
                                .removeClass('ativo')
                                .next()
                                .show(800)
                                .addClass('ativo');
                        }
                     });</script>";
                }
            }
            ?>

            <div class="input-group md-input">
                <span class="input-group-addon pq-txt" id="basic-addon1">웃</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="15" id="user" name="user" required="" placeholder="Usuário">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group md-input">
                <span class="input-group-addon pq-txt" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required="" placeholder="Email">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group md-input">
                <span class="input-group-addon md-txt" id="basic-addon1">#*</span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="15" id="senha" required="" name="pass1" placeholder="Senha">
                <span class="input-group-addon md-txt confirm" id="basic-addon1"><span class="confirm" >#*</span></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control confirm" maxlength="15" id="senha2" required=""  name="pass2" placeholder="Confirmar Senha">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1">
            <div class="barprogress" >
                <div></div>
            </div><br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success md-btn" value="Próximo"/>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 33.3%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-content modal-person modal-person2">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title md-title">Registrar</h4>
            <h5 class="modal-title md-title">perfil</h5>
        </div>
        <?php
            if (isset($_REQUEST['error'])) {
                $erro = $_REQUEST['error'];
                if ($erro == "userexist") {
                    echo "<b class=\"text-danger\">Usuário ou email já cadastrado!</b>";
                    echo "<p class=\"text-danger\">Veja-os novamente..<br><br>";
                } else if ($erro == "passdistint") {
                    echo "<b class=\"text-danger\">Senhas são distintas!</b>";
                    echo "<p class=\"text-danger\">Os campos de senha devem ter a mesma senha..<br><br>";
                } else if ($erro == "every") {
                    echo "<b class=\"text-danger\">Erro desconhecido!</b>";
                    echo "<p class=\"text-danger\">Tente novamente mais tarde...<br><br>";
                } else if ($erro == "sucess2") {
                    echo "<script>
                    $(function(){
                        if($('.ativo').next().size())
                        {
                            $('.ativo')
                                .hide(800)
                                .removeClass('ativo')
                                .next()
                                .show(800)
                                .addClass('ativo');
                        }
                     });</script>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <center><img src="..." alt="..." width="100" height="100" class="img-circle perfil"></center><br>
            <div class="input-group pq-input">
                <span class="input-group-addon pq-txt" id="basic-addon1">웃</span>
                <input type="file" class="form-control btn btn-default md-btn fileimg" accept="image/*"  name="img" required="" >
            </div>

            <div class="input-group md-input">
                <span class="input-group-addon md-txt" id="basic-addon1">Nome</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="200" required="" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group md-input">
                <span class="input-group-addon md-txt" id="basic-addon1">Nascimento</span>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" required="" name="data">
                <span class="input-group-addon md-txt" id="basic-addon1">Profissão</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" required=""  name="profissao" placeholder="Trabalho em..">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success md-btn" value="Próximo"/>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 66.6%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

A primeira parte (onde o usuário informa login, email e senha) é confirmada assim:

```
$mnpdo = new MinPDO();
$step = $_REQUEST['step'];
if($step == 1) {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['user']) and isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
        $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        try {
            $result = $mnpdo->consult("users", "*", "email = '$email' or username = '$user'");
            if($result[0]["username"] == $user or $result[0]["email"] == $email) {
                header("location:../singup.php?error=userexist");
                exit();
            }    
        } catch (MinPDOException $ex) {
            if($ex->getMessage() != "No results!") {
                header("location:../singup.php?error=".$ex->getMessage());
                exit();
            }

        }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['pass1'])) {
            $pass1 = $_REQUEST['pass1'];

            if(isset($_REQUEST['pass2'])) {
                $pass2 = $_REQUEST['pass2'];
                if($pass1 != $pass2) {
                    header("location:../singup.php?error=passdistint");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    header("location:../singup.php?error=sucess");
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                header("location:../singup.php?error=pass2");
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            header("location:../singup.php?error=pass");
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header("location:../singup.php?error=user");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Quando ele valida retorno `sucess` e assim eu faço a ação para ir para a próxima etapa..

Como faço para quando ele voltar com o `sucess` ou até mesmo com falha ele não perder os dados que foram validados?

Estava pensando em a medida que for validando ir armazenando os valores em um array `$validado['meuinput']` e ao retornar com o head pegar os valores do array, mas como passo o array para a página? (sem ser por url - get)

Comment: Acho que você pode usar variáveis de sessão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode armazenr o array em uma variável de sessão... As váriáveis de sessão podem ser acessadas de qualquer página, o que resolveria o problema de transito de informações... Ex:

```
    $_SESSION["nomeDaVariavel"] = $seuArray;
```

A cada item novo que você adicionar ao array, será necessário atualizar a variável de sessão, utilizando o mesmo comando acima.

Quando ocorrer alguma falha no processo de autenticação, você destrói a variável de sessão. Ex:

```
    if($result[0]["username"] == $user or $result[0]["email"] == $email) {
            header("location:../singup.php?error=userexist");
            unset($_SESSION['nomeDaVariavel']);
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: Olá Andre, acho que você poderia melhorar esta resposta, incluindo alguma explicação, e um exemplo de como fazer isso.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, @gustavox. Realmente, estava fraca mesmo... Obrigado pelo feedback... =)

Comment: Ficou legal André. +1

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar `$_SESSION`, assim que entrar na validação do passo grava na sessão:

`session_start();
$_SESSION["meuinput"] = "valor";
$_SESSION["meuinput2"] = "2";
session_write_close();`

Dai depois de redirecionar na tela do formulário é só inputar os dados:

```html
<?php

session_start();

?>

<input type="text" value="<?=isset($_SESSION['meuinput'])?$_SESSION['meuinput']:'';?>">
```

Comment: Faltou o `echo` no value.

Comment: Na verdade não faltou não, pois o `<?=` é o mesmo que `<?php echo`

Comment: Eu tentei assim, acusou erro no `=` '-'

Comment: Ahhh, faz sentido o que vc falou então, pois para usar o `=` depende da configuração do PHP, no meu aqui tá funcionando porque minha configuração permite. Valeu